# Python Django ModelForm has no model class specified error

Tags: django, modelform

I want to write an inventory manager. i written a django app before and in the first app everything works fine, but now i got a problem.
when i try to render the template i get the error:

- ModelForm has no model class specified -

i looked up some forums and here in stack overflow was a guy with the same error, but he did only a typo. i checked my code threetimes, everything should be correct...

my model:

class Device (models.Model):

```
inventory_number = models.IntegerField()
device_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
is_used = models.BooleanField()
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, blank=True)
vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, blank=True)
note = models.TextField(blank=True)
purchase_date = models.DateField(blank=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

my modelform :

```
class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Metal:
        model = Device
```

my view:

def create_device(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    device_form = DeviceForm(request.POST)
    if device_form.is_valid():
        device_form.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect ('/Inventory/')
device_form = DeviceForm()

c = RequestContext (request,{
    'device_form' : device_form
})
return render_to_response('create_device.html', c)
```

my template:

Inventar erfassen

the imports are correct... i rly don't know where i can find the fault
thank u for help

Answer (score 3):

It could just be a typo, but `class Metal` in the ModelForm should be `class Meta`:

```
class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
```